# Mass Update on Laravel 5 Collection

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I am working on a project where I will need to get at least 100k data from SQL table (the data is a 6 digit code indexed on the table), export them into a CSV file and run an update query to update their status.

The export time takes only seconds but because of the update queries it's taking a long time. I am looking for an efficient way to do this task.

Here's my code:

```
    $filename = 'sample.csv';
    $handle = fopen($filename, 'w+');

    $collection = Code::select('code')->where('status', 0)->take($request->quantity)->get();

    foreach ($collection->chunk(500) as $codes) {
        foreach ($codes as $code) {
            fputcsv($handle, [
              $code->code,
              ]);
              // this update query making the whole process taking long time
              Code::where('code', $code->code)->update(['status' => 1]); 
        }
    }

    fclose($handle);
```

I am looking for a better way to update those data. Any suggestions?

Comment: I thought Laravel 5 had a method to execute an update on a collection, not just on individual models in that collection

Comment: No. They didn't. Here's a list of available methods you can use with collection: http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-collections#available-methods

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you just do a bulk update after the file has been written?

```
$filename = 'sample.csv';
$handle = fopen($filename, 'w+');

$query = Code::select('code')->where('status', 0)->take($request->quantity);

foreach ($query->get()->chunk(500) as $codes) {
    foreach ($codes as $code) {
        fputcsv($handle, [
          $code->code,
          ]);
    }
}
$query->update(['status' => 1]); // Update all of them in one go

fclose($handle);
```

Comment: I tried your code but faced problems. First, _chunk()_ method couldn't run with _$query_, it expected a closure as a second argument.  Second, when I fixed it with a closure, it was taking all the rows from _code_ table instead of the quantity specified.

Comment: I fixed the issue with this code:
`$collection = Code::select('code')->where('status', 0)->orderBy('id', 'asc')->take($request->quantity);
        $handle = fopen($filename, 'w+');

        foreach ($collection->get()->chunk(500) as $codes) {
            foreach ($codes as $code) {
                fputcsv($handle, [
                  $code->code,
                  ]);
            }
        }

        fclose($handle);
        $collection->update(['status' => 1]);`

Comment: good point, I've updated the answer with that.. Just realised that take() and chunk() doesn't work together.. hmm..